# svn checkout to viewvc link give back redirecting url error

Tags: svn

I'm trying to svn checkout the following:

```
http://website.com/viewvc/tool
but I get the error:
SVN: E195019 Redirect cycle detected for URL...
```

I'm not quite sure if I should be using the viewvc link to svn checkout, but I couldn't find anything else to checkout with on the viewvc page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the SVN command you're actually using? BTW the page address you gave gives a 404 error.

Comment: @Michael svn checkout http://somerandomwebsite.com/viewvc/tool also the link I gave is not an actual link.

Comment: Are you pointing your checkout to a symbolic link?

Comment: @Michael i have no idea. The link I'm using is simply the viewvc link that lets me see the SVN on the browser.

Comment: You might find [this](http://www.svnforum.org/archive/index.php/t-37598.html) helpful. It looks like you can't check out a viewvc URL.

Comment: @Michael cool that worked, changed viewvc to svn, thanks!

Comment: Great. I suggest you post the answer to your own question so that others can find it in the future.

Comment: Is there any hint when the viewvc installation is being accessed through http://website.com/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Michael's help I was able to get my answer. Basically viewvc URLs are not the same as SVN urls and cannot be interpreted in the same way. calling svn checkout with a viewvc link would not work. All you have to do is change the link:

```
website.com/viewvc/tool
to
website.com/svn/tool
```

and svn should work as usual