# what is the command to get a package from svn pecl with the trunk url?

Tags: bash, pecl

i want to get the trunk this package

http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/kakasi/trunk/

so i can phpize configre make make install and so on

so i tried

```
svn checkout http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/kakasi/trunk
```

but it outputs

```
Redirecting to URL 'http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/kakasi/trunk':
Redirecting to URL 'http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/kakasi/trunk':
svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/kakasi/trunk'
```

and it doesnt get the contents

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001177/svn-checkout-to-viewvc-link-give-back-redirecting-url-error

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001177/svn-checkout-to-viewvc-link-give-back-redirecting-url-error), `/viewvc/` URLs are not real SVN URLs. You'll need to replace `/viewvc/` with something else, depending on how the server is configured. Some use `/svn/`, or in the case of PHP's repository, you want `/repository/`. Thus, you want:

```
svn checkout http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/kakasi/trunk
```